# How to simplify query with joins and similar where clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization

I have multiple `Stored Procedures` that have joins with similar where clauses, in fact the only difference is the `FROM` table. I would like to remove the duplication if possible. This is a working example:

```
SELECT x.Month_Name
 , x.Invoice_Amt
 , y.Payment_Amt
FROM
(
    SELECT d.Month_Name
         , d.Month
         , sum(i.Amount) AS Invoice_Amt
    FROM Invoice i
         INNER JOIN DATE d ON i.Trans_Date = d.PK_Date
    WHERE d.Month BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-02-01'
          AND i.Account = '1-AAA'
    GROUP BY d.Month
           , d.Month_Name
) x
JOIN
(
    SELECT d.Month_Name
         , sum(p.Amount) AS Payment_Amt
    FROM Payment p
         INNER JOIN DATE d ON p.Payment_Date = d.PK_Date
    WHERE d.Month BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-02-01'
          AND p.Account = '1-AAA'
    GROUP BY d.month
           , d.month_Name
) y ON x.Month_Name = y.Month_Name
ORDER BY x.Month
       , x.Month_Name;
```

This is a non-working example of what I'm aiming for:

```
SELECT d.Month_Name
     , d.Month
     , sum(i.Amount) AS Invoice_Amt
     , sum(p.Amount) AS Payment_Amt
FROM Invoice i
     INNER JOIN DATE d ON i.Trans_Date = d.PK_Date
     JOIN Payment p ON i.Account = p.Account
WHERE d.Month BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-02-01'
      AND i.Account = '1-AAA'
GROUP BY d.Month
       , d.Month_Name
ORDER BY d.Month
       , d.Month_Name;
```

The database schema as I can't get SQL Fiddle working.

```
CREATE TABLE Date
(PK_Date    datetime,
 Month      datetime,
 Month_Name varchar(20));

INSERT INTO Date
VALUES
('2016-01-01', '2016-01-01', 'January 2016'),
('2016-01-15', '2016-01-01', 'January 2016'),
('2016-02-04', '2016-02-01', 'February 2016'),
('2016-02-15', '2016-02-01', 'February 2016');

CREATE TABLE Invoice
(Account    varchar(15),
Trans_Date datetime,
Amount     float);

INSERT INTO Invoice
VALUES
('1-AAA', '2016-01-01', 521.32),
('1-AAA', '2016-02-04', 854.20);

CREATE TABLE Payment
(Account      varchar(15),
Payment_Date datetime,
Amount       float);

INSERT INTO Payment
VALUES
('1-AAA', '2016-01-15', 410.50), 
('1-AAA', '2016-02-15', 120.98);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [DATE] as a base table and left outer join [Invoice] & [Payment].
like so:

```
SELECT d.Month_Name
     , d.Month
     , sum(i.Amount) AS Invoice_Amt
     , sum(p.Amount) AS Payment_Amt
FROM DATE d 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Invoice i ON i.Trans_Date = d.PK_Date
LEFT OUTER JOIN Payment p ON p.Payment_Date = d.PK_Date
WHERE d.Month BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-02-01'
      AND (i.Account = '1-AAA' OR p.Account = '1-AAA')
GROUP BY d.Month
       , d.Month_Name
ORDER BY d.Month
       , d.Month_Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need [date] table at all.
[Updated query >>](http://pastebin.com/0UwgwHDK)

```html
DECLARE @dt_from DATETIME  = '2016-01-01';
DECLARE @dt_to  DATETIME  = '2016-02-01';
DECLARE @acc  VARCHAR(256) = '1-AAA';


SELECT
  [Month_Name] = DATENAME(MONTH, [agg_data].[dt]) + SPACE(1) + CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, [agg_data].[dt]) AS VARCHAR(4))
-- ,[Month]  = [agg_data].[dt]
 ,[Invoice_Amt] = [agg_data].[amount_inv]
 ,[Payment_Amt] = [agg_data].[amount_pmt]
FROM
 (
  SELECT
     [dt]   = ISNULL([i].[dt], [p].[dt])     
    ,[amount_inv] = ISNULL([i].[amount], 0)
    ,[amount_pmt] = ISNULL([p].[amount], 0)
    ,[acc]   = ISNULL([i].[acc], [p].[acc])
  FROM
   (
    SELECT
      [acc]  = [account]  
     ,[dt]  = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([trans_date]), MONTH([trans_date]), 1)
     ,[amount] = SUM([amount])
    FROM
     [invoice]
    GROUP BY
      DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([trans_date]), MONTH([trans_date]), 1)
     ,[account]
   ) AS [i]
  FULL JOIN
   ( 
    SELECT
      [acc]  = [account]  
     ,[dt]  = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([payment_date]), MONTH([payment_date]), 1)
     ,[amount] = SUM([amount])
    FROM
     [payment]
    GROUP BY
      DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([payment_date]), MONTH([payment_date]), 1)
     ,[account]
   ) AS [p]
  ON
    [i].[acc] = [p].[acc]
   AND [i].[dt] = [p].[dt]
 ) AS [agg_data]
WHERE
  [dt] BETWEEN @dt_from AND @dt_to
 AND [acc] =  @acc
ORDER BY
  [dt] ASC;
```